# Proving inf and sup of a set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

$$s:=\{(1/2n) - (1/(2m+1))\} n,m \in N$$

I know that the inf is $-1/3$ and the sup is $1/2$. I know to prove this I that I have to show they are the greatest lowerbound and least upperbound respectively but do I have to prove that $(1/2n)$ is decreasing and bounded $0$ and that $- (1/(2m+1)$ is increasing and bounded by $0$ first.

I'm unsure about what exactly I have to prove.

Comment: Those two are nice *observations*.

Comment: The archimedean principle: if $x$ is any real number, there is a natural number $n$ such that $n > x$. This is a basic property of real numbers, so it should have been proven for you already. To use it: if $\epsilon > 0$, then $1/\epsilon$ certainly is a real number,

Answer (score 0):

TO show $-1/3$ is the greatest lowerbound of the set you need the fact that $1/2n$ goes to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$, of course all the elements in the set is greater than $-1/3$, now say $-1/3$ is not the greatest lowerbound, say $x$ is the greatest lowerbound, so $x>-1/3$ , so no term of the sequence must lie between $(-1/3,x)$ as $x$ is the greatest lowerbound

Now fix $m=1$, now as $1/2n$ goes to zero there is a term in the set which lies in the interval  $(-1/3,x)$, hence a contradiction, so $-1/3$ is the greatest lowerbound.

Now to prove the least upperbound you need the fact that $−(1/(2m+1)$  is increasing and bounded by $0$.

I hope everything is clear to you now, proceed similarly for the least upperbound.